# how can i join all my dataframes into one dataframe in for loop one after one without headers?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

this is my code i need to join all dataframes in for loop into one dataframe.and i need to write dataframe into csv file.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

for i in range(2,636):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen("https://www.wisdomjobs.com/core-java-
  jobs-" + str(i), "lxml").read())
  #print soup
  all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
  #print all_tables
  A=[]
  B=[]
  C=[]
  for right_table in all_tables:
    for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
        cells = row.findAll('td')
        states=row.findAll('th') #To store second column data
        if len(cells)==3: #Only extract table body not heading
            A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
            B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
            C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
  #print "\n Generate lists ", A, B, C
  df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=["Company and Job Title"])
  df["Location"] = B
  df['Posted On'] = C
  df
  #print '\n table', df
  #df.to_csv('core_java2.csv')
  with open('foo.csv', 'a') as f:
     pd.concat([df], axis=1).to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Comment: someone please help me with this

Comment: Did you try `pd.concat`? What is your exact problem? This example looks much too complicated. Please reduce it.

Comment: my code is giving multiple dataframes . i need to join all dataframes into one data frame

Comment: so that i can write all my output into one csv file

Comment: so `pd.concat` them after collecting them in a list.

Comment: You shouldn't be concatenating a dataframe, and definitely not writing to file, every pass through the loop. Declare the lists before the loop, append to those lists inside the loop, then when the loop is finished, create the dataframe from those lists, and write to file, once.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) in loop, append output to `list`, create final `DataFrame` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and last write to file by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
dfs = []
for i in range(2,636):
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.wisdomjobs.com/core-java-jobs-' + str(i))[1]
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df.head())


df.to_csv('foo.csv')
```

---

If need modify your solution append `df` in loop to `list` and last `concat`:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(2,636):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen("https://www.wisdomjobs.com/core-java-
  jobs-" + str(i), "lxml").read())
  #print soup
  all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
  #print all_tables
  A=[]
  B=[]
  C=[]
  for right_table in all_tables:
    for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
        cells = row.findAll('td')
        states=row.findAll('th') #To store second column data
        if len(cells)==3: #Only extract table body not heading
            A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
            B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
            C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
  #print "\n Generate lists ", A, B, C
  df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=["Company and Job Title"])
  df["Location"] = B
  df['Posted On'] = C
  dfs.append(df)
  #print '\n table', df
  #df.to_csv('core_java2.csv')

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df.head())

df.to_csv('foo.csv')
```